# Find angle between complex vectors

Tags: complex-numbers, vectors, angle

I need to work out the angle $\theta$ between these two complex vectors:

$$u=(1+i,2-i)$$
$$v=(2-3i,4+i)$$

I understand I must utilize the following formula:

$$||u|| ||v|| cos(\theta)=\Re(<u,v>)$$

I am unsure how to calculate the modulus $||u||$ of a complex vector though.

Is it:

$$\sqrt{||u_1||^2 + ||u_2||^2} = \sqrt{7}$$

Or something else?

Comment: What is going on with your title? Please edit...

Comment: Whoops! Somehow a previous question I wrote but never posted overrode the title before I posted this one. Thanks Morgan for the edit

Answer (score 0):

In general, the angle $\theta$ between two complex vectors $u$ and $v$ (itself possibly complex) is given by
$$
\theta = \cos^{-1}\frac{u\cdot{v^H}}{\left\lVert{u}\right\rVert\left\lVert{v}\right\rVert}
$$
For the example above, $v^H$ = $(2+3i,4-i)$ and $u\cdot{v^H}$ = $6 - i$. The norm of a complex vector $u = \{u_1, u_2,  \dots, u_n\}$ is given by
$$
\left\lVert{u}\right\rVert = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\ u_iu_i^*} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\ \left|u_i\right|^2}
$$
This, of course, reduces to the standard (Euclidean) norm for real vectors. We see for $u$ and $v$ above the norms are $\left\lVert{u}\right\rVert = \sqrt{7}$ and $\left\lVert{v}\right\rVert = \sqrt{30}$ respectively, yielding a value for the angle between the vectors of
$$
\theta = \cos^{-1}\frac{6-i}{\sqrt{210}} \approx 1.14521 + 0.0756928i
$$

Comment: It would be interesting with some geometric interpretation of this angle

Comment: I'm not sure what that interpretation is, because a complex angle isn't anything we have any real-world experience with. In general it's hard to visualise things that are $\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ because we can't think in four dimensions. Note also that the inner product of two complex vectors is not commutative unlike the real version (although it retains nice properties like bilinearity and the triangle inequality).

Comment: Where did you get a formula for a complex angle? You should be using the underlying real inner product, i.e., the real part of the hermitian inner product.